# Empty object type that intersects nicely with non-empty object

Tags: typescript

What type can I use for an "empty object", that doesn't permit properties, but can still be inter**sect**ed with another non-empty type?

Perhaps it is clearer with an example:

```
type A = {a: number}
type Empty = {}

const mixture: A & Empty = {a: 1}
const empty: Empty = {}                 // Works ok with Empty={}
const enforceEmpty: Empty = {a: 1}      // Should fail, but permitted with Empty={}
```

I have also tried `type Empty = Record<any, never>`, but in this case `A & Empty` can't be unified and doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```js
type A = { a: number }

type Empty = { __tag?: never }

const mixture: A & Empty = { a: 1 } // ok

const empty: Empty = {}  // ok   

const enforceEmpty: Empty = { a: 1 } // error

const drawback: Empty = { __tag: undefined } // allowed
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwCgLRIoBRPMUBZKAfTeFQHMB%20TLBABuJclQDGAeywBnYFDwBLAB7AcxCJjgAyeo2aIUGKAEZyUAPQWokgNYTpcqBH0hMDJiBZIyUS9bs-KAdZeQgsADNJYnEID1B3V280TDNfK2diYmiQpwATYlQAdwJUcVtEz2SOLm5MHCw8iAjFQTyxKgogA)

You can use branded types.

As you might have noticed, there is a drawback: `const drawback: Empty = { __tag: undefined }`

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking for something without this drawback, ideally, but maybe no such type is possible in TS?

Comment: I dont think it is possible, because object with props is always assignable to empty object.